# How to debug the ProcessRequest method in a generic handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, debugging

I'm developing an ASP.NET application that uses a generic handler to receive HTTP POST and retrieve data from it for displaying on the main page. Now I want to go into the ProcessRequest method of the generic handler I use to check if it works when debugging my application. How can I do it? Can I send a HTTP POST to my application to trigger the method under debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

- Start your application in debug mode
- Invoke your handler using an outside program/tool

[Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) is really good at this.

Answer (score 0):

First start your application in debug mode after use below tools for debug your application.

Use **Advance Rest Client** For Debug your application in Chrome or Firefox.

Chrome : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Firefox : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/